# JFileChooser.showOpenDialog not opening, and no error being thrown?

Tags: java, swing, hex, jfilechooser

Okay, so I'm trying to make a hex editor, and I'm trying to make a load JMenuItem, but it's not working. The JFileChooser OpenDialog just doesn't show up, and no errors are being shown.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class HexEditor extends JFrame{
    JTextArea textArea;
    JFileChooser chooser;// = new JFileChooser();
    FileInputStream fin;
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu file;
        JMenuItem load;

    public HexEditor(){
        super("Cypri's java hex editor");

        chooser = new JFileChooser();

        load = new JMenuItem("Load");
            load.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {


                    try{

                        openFile();
                        fin = new FileInputStream(chooser.getSelectedFile());

                        int ch;
                        StringBuffer strContent = new StringBuffer("");

                        for(int i = 0; (ch = fin.read()) != -1; i++){
                            String s = Integer.toHexString(ch);

                            if(s.length() < 2)
                                s = "0" + Integer.toHexString(ch);

                            if(i < 10)
                                strContent.append(" " + s.toUpperCase());

                            else{
                                strContent.append(" " + s.toUpperCase() + "\n");
                                i = 0;
                            }
                        }

                        textArea.setText(strContent.toString());
                        //textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
                        //textArea.setColumns(50);
                        //textArea.setRows(50);
                    }

                    catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

        file = new JMenu("File");
        file.add(new JMenuItem("Load"));

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.add(file);

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setSize(300,300);
        textArea.setText("Hello\n");
        textArea.append(" world!");




        setSize(640, 480);
        //getContentPane().setBackground(Color.);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, menuBar);
        getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, textArea);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void openFile(){
        chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        HexEditor app = new HexEditor();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never add the JMenuItem with the listener, instead you create a new one.

Replace:

```
file.add(new JMenuItem("Load"));
```

with

```
file.add(load);
```

Comment: That worked, and I will except this answer as soon as I can. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is everything being done in the event dispatch thread? You'll get small errors like this if it isn't.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2007/jw-08-swingthreading.html

http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=8963

Also, look at http://www.fifesoft.com/hexeditor/ for a neat hex editor component under a BSD license :)

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public static void main(String[] args){
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
            HexEditor app = new HexEditor();
       }
    };
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
}
```

Comment: had nothing to do with his problem :)

Comment: I wouldn't say that. He's doing stuff in the main thread directly, which is an absolute recipe for disaster.

Comment: I would say that, but you are right. You really ought to start on the EDT.

Comment: Sorry, you're right :) That was the main problem at hand. I initially read the question as the entire form not displaying. Oof.